# C - binary Char to double

Tags: c, char, double, bin

We got a programming task from the university. we should write a program that reads from a bin file double values. The double values ​​in the bin file have like the following appearance:
[image: bin doubles]

The program successfully reads all values ​​as CharArray, but I don't understand how to convert this Char array with the values ​​into double.
I am not yet programming C too long. I hope someone can help me find a solution.

my Code so far:

```
typedef struct {
    char magic[16];
    char dataType[16];
    char elementCount[16];
} FileHeader;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int n;
    double *values;
} FileData;

//---METHODEN 

FileData readBinaryValues (const char *filename){

    FileData error;
    error.n = 0;
    error.values = NULL;

    FILE *datei = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
    if (datei == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: Datei nicht gefunden\n");
        return error;
    }

    FileHeader fH;
    fscanf(datei,"%16c%16c%16c",fH.magic,fH.dataType,fH.elementCount );

    char testMagic[16] = "STATDATA";
    char testDataType[16] = "DOUBLE";
    if ( strcmp(testMagic,fH.magic) != 0){

        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: Unerwarteter Magic\n");
        printf("%s\n",fH.magic);
        fclose(datei);
        printf("%s\n",fH.magic);
        return error;

    } else if (strcmp(testDataType,fH.dataType) != 0){

        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: Unerwarteter DataType\n");
        fclose(datei);
        return error;

    } else {

        int elmentCount = atoi(fH.elementCount);
        FileData result;
        result.values = (double*) malloc(elmentCount * sizeof(double));

        if (result.values == NULL){

            fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: Zu wenig HeapSpeicher\n");
            fclose(datei);
            return error;
        }

        int posE = (3*16)-1; 
        fseek(datei, posE , SEEK_SET); //start double-elements 




        char memBlock [sizeof(double)]; //memoryblock 


        int j = 0;
        int i  = 0;
        for (j=0;j<=10;j++){ //only 10 doubles for testing 

            for (i = 0;i<(int)sizeof(double);i++){ //sizeof(double) durchläufe 


                memBlock[i] = fgetc(datei);
            }

            if(memBlock == NULL){ //fängt nichts ab 
                fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: Unerwartetes Dateiende\n");
                fclose(datei);
                return error;
            }

            printf("%x\n",memBlock);
            snprintf(memBlock,sizeof(double),"%.8e", result.values[j]);

            //result.values[j] =strtod(memBlock,NULL);
            //result.values (double*)memBlock;
            //memcpy(&result.values[j],memBlock,sizeof(double));
            //result.values[j] = atof(memBlock);
            result.values[j] = *((double*)memBlock);
            //result.values[j] = atof(memBlock); //-------------------- string in double 
            //memcpy(&result.values[j],memBlock,sizeof(double)); //bin -> double

            printf("%i)%lf\n",j,result.values[j]);
        }
    result.n = elmentCount; 
    return result;
    }


}
```

sry but some comments and errors are written in German.
The FileHeader describes the appearance of the .bin file. Magic comes first as dataType and then the number of double elements in .bin. immediately followed by so many double values.
The program still checks whether magic = STATDATA and dataType = DOUBLE.

Comment: IEEE 754 double precision floating point value takes up 8 bytes of space. Why are your arrays 16 bytes long? Anyway, if the data is stored as IEEE 754, and endianness in the file matches your machine's endianness, then you can simply [copy the array into a `double` using `memcpy`](https://godbolt.org/z/HfGzbS). If you need to convert big endian to little endian or vice versa, you will have to reverse the array first.

Answer (score 0):

Check out for

```
strtod()
```

Documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/).